# How do I find this distance?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

> Find the minimum and maximum distances between the ellipse $x^2+xy+2y^2 = 1$ and the origin.

This is what I've attempted so far:

Maximize $x^2+y^2+z^2$ with respect to $x^2+xy+2y^2 = 1$. Using Lagrange multipliers, we get the system of equations:

$$2x = \lambda(2x+y)$$
$$2y = \lambda(x+4y)$$
$$0 = \lambda z$$
$$x^2+xy+2y^2 = 1$$

I do not know how to solve this system. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Where does $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ come from?

Comment: It would be nice if you could type out the question, it is very small...

Comment: @Nameless Sure, fixed it :)

Comment: @GFauxPas That's the function you wanna maximize if you want to maximize distance. The distance function has a squareroot, but the squareroot can be dropped when your trying to find the maximum and minimum of the function.

Comment: Distance in $\mathbb R^3$, or distance in $\mathbb R^2$? If you're in $\mathbb R^2$, why are you defining a new coordinate $z$?

Comment: @GFauxPas In $R^3$. The origin is at $(0,0,0)$, while  the ellipse is a level curve lying on $z=1$.

Comment: You can solve this with more pure geometry too. Find the axes of the ellipse.

Comment: That's a very strange way to think of it. You're on the plane $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$, and on the plane you have a curve. You're drawing a line between a point on the curve to the origin. Otherwise, you might as well say you're in $\mathbb R^5$, on the level space $z = 1, w = 0, v = 0$, and silly things like that.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  You can minimize/maximize $r^2=x^2+y^2$ instead of $r$.  You have $r^2=-y^2-xy+1$  Use your equation to get an expression for $x$ in terms of $y$ and substitute it in.  Take the derivative with respect to $y$, set to zero, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest finding the axes of the ellipse using purely geometry (plus coordinate algebra) ways. This may require some knowledge of how to manipulate bilinear forms but I think most precalc textbooks cover it for conics, so I assume fair game.